# When I am trying to add the image in layout the app is working fine in lollipop but crashes in marshmallow

Tags: android, kotlin

When I am trying to add the image in layout the app is working fine in lollipop but crashes in marshmallow. If that images is removed then app works fine. It gives error when image is inserted and gives error in line SetContentview of kotlin page.

---

This is XML CODE

```
<LinearLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/back"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:contentDescription="Logo of App"
    android:src="@drawable/echoi"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    /> //When adding this image the app crashes in marshmellow and is working fine in lolipop.

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="p1"
        android:text="1 Player"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="p2"
        android:text="2 Player"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is Kotlin Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)//After crashin in logcat it shows this line has error.
    }
    public fun p1(view: View)
    {
        val intent: Intent = Intent(applicationContext,Oneplayer::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

    public fun p2(view: View)
    {
        val intent: Intent = Intent(applicationContext,Twoplayer::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: can  you update your question with crash log

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ID `"@+id/img"` is unique and not used anywhere else.

Did you try to remove `android:contentDescription` attribute?

Comment: Yes I tried without content description it still gave the same error and ID is unique and is not used anywhere else.

Comment: I guess we need the Crash log to get further in this